# NullPointerException when trying to apply custom font to a button

Tags: java, android, button, nullpointerexception, typeface

I declared

```
public Button testbutton;
public Typeface font;
```

in my MainActivity.java.

Then, in onWindowFocusChanged() inside the MainActivity, I put in

```
testbutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.testbutton);
font=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "condensed.ttf");
testbutton.setTypeface(font);
```

and then there's an error happening:

```
08-16 16:33:40.078 27339 27339 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setTypeface(android.graphics.Typeface)' on a null object reference
```

But the button isn't null, because I'm using an OnClickListener on it already which displays a toast when clicking the button (but in the onCreate method)

What am I doing wrong? It works for many others, and they all couldn't help me.

**EDIT:**

Apparently I had to initialize the Button variables inside onCreate(), but if I want to do the same with a TextView, I have to initialize the TextView variable inside onWindowsFocusChanged().
This information is for people having the same problem in future.

Comment: And if anyone tells me that I should try it with the onCreate(): No. Even TextViews, which aren't loaded, are null there when trying it. In the onWindowFocusChanged(), TextViews aren't null on initializing.

Comment: Why are you doing it  onWindowFocusChanged() do it in onCreate()

Comment: Might be the font itself which makes you problems.

Comment: @NarendraKothamire Are you kidding me? No, in onCreate, it's too early.

Comment: @TeodorLiv No. Look at the error, it's definitely the button.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should verify the font path `condensed.ttf` file.

Sometimes you will need to reuse **Typeface** so you can make some like this or you can create a **CustomView**:

1-Create **assets** directory in to *main* folder, I usually create another folder (**fonts directory**) into assets.

src -- > main -- > assets -- > fonts(optional)

2-Create a class Fonts for example.

```
public class CustomFonts {

//beware if you use other folder into assets (/fonts/condensed.ttf).

private final static String CONDENSED_FONT = "condensed.ttf";

public static Typeface typefaceCondensed(Context context) {
return Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getResources().getAssets(),
CONDENSED_FONT);
    }

}
```

3-apply font

```
yourView.setTypeface(CustomFonts.typefaceCondensed(your_context));
```

In your case

```
testButton.setTypeface(CustomFonts.typefaceCondensed(this));
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: Well, it does not fix the NullPointerException, which says that the button variable is null, even if it isn't.

Comment: Can you show me more code XML and your Class? Is assets directory name right?, You could verify with other file font maybe itself which makes errors.

Comment: The XML is not wrong, that's sure,. And the fonts path is assets/[font files], and there is no font having a similar name or so, when I use a TextView, it works, and the Button has an OnClickListener on it, soo....

Comment: Even though your answer wasn't your solution, it helped me with organizing font styles, thanks! The solution is in my question now. I also want to tell you that it's better to use "public static class CustomFonts" and "public final static String CONDENSED_FONT".